# Change month in SharePoint MonthlyCalendarView control

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, calendar, visual-web-part

How to change month in SharePoint MonthlyCalendarView Control? It seems, there is no way to change month in calendar or change view of calendar.

Comment: I am having the same issue when the calendar is added to a page as a web part. When viewing the calendar view of a list directly, the ribbon works as normal, but when it is viewed as a web part, the ribbon either isn't visible, or the day, week, and month views are disabled. Is this the same issue?